# Does Micronaut support Hibernate OGM?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

Does Micronaut support Hibernate OGM?

If not, is there a way to add Hibernate OGM to Micronaut? I guess Micronaut should provide any extension mechanism like custom type mapper, converters or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Does Micronaut support Hibernate OGM?

There is no explicit support in Micronaut for Hibernate OGM, but Hibernate OGM may be used in a Micronaut service.

> If no, how this support may be added?

That would depend on what the support is supposed to accomplish.